# How to launch Remote debug for Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, apache-spark, remote-debugging, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to do remote debug with zeppelin. I added the below in my /etc/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh:

```
export ZEPPELIN_MEM="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8111
```

Also created a remote debug in IntelliJ, I gave the command line argument for running remote JVM :

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8111
```

when I try to start the zeppelin server with :

```
 sudo -u zeppelin /usr/lib/zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh restart
```

it shows :

```
Zeppelin stop [ OK ]
Zeppelin start [ OK ]
```

But when I try to launch zeppelin via ssh tunnel (on mac) :

```
ssh -i ec2-key-pair.pem -N -L 8058:localhost:8089 hadoop@ec2-34-109-123-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

It shows :

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

In the IntelliJ:

```
10:04 PM    Error running Remote: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8111): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `8058:localhost:8111` ? I mean don't you need to create the tunnel to the debugging port?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a double quote `"` at the end of line added in `zeppelin-env.sh`